# How can I change using jekyll bootstrap navbar colour?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

Jekyll and bootstrap theme from http://jekyllbootstrap.com/ work fine but, no matter where I dig around or change css settings I can not manage to change the various colour settings for the navbar. Where do I actually make the appropriate colour changes, or how can I determine where the navbar colour settings reside?  I also see some references to changing css files and adding html somewhere, do I need to do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's anything like the default navbar for bootstrap, some of these should affect to it:

```
.nav {
   background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.nav a {
   color: #FFF;
}
```

And if it's still not affecting in anyhow, you should check the correct divs for your case through **inspector**, which can be accessed by right clicking the element you want to inspect.

Also try to mark some attributes as **!important**, because sometimes your CSS-styling doesn't quite override the defaults of bootstrap.

So, it goes like this:

```
background-color: rgb(125,0,55) !important;
```

If you need some further help with this, please provide us a fiddle or some sort of a code from HTML & CSS you have.

Comment: I managed to find some of these settings in /root/assets/themes/bootstrap-3/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css !  This file is a mess, hard to edit but found the current settings with the use of the browser inspector as you suggested and then made some changes, now works! Must be a better way but it works!

Comment: Glad that helped you! I don't know if there are better ways to do it or not, but it's working at least. Take care!